# find the number of lines in a file

Tags: r, windows

Under Linux, I can find the number of lines in a file by doing a system call to `wc`:

```
CountLines <- function(file) {
   count.file <- system(sprintf("wc -l %s", file), intern = TRUE)
   count <- as.integer(strsplit(count.file, " ")[[1]][1])
   return(count)
}
```

How can I do this efficiently under Windows? By "efficient" I mean fast and light on resources, as I may be using it on large files.

As much as possible, I'd prefer a solution that does not require installing extra packages or tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this link:

https://isc.sans.edu/diary/Finding+Files+and+Counting+Lines+at+the+Windows+Command+Prompt/2244

The last line works for me:

```
c:\> type c:\windows\win.ini | find /c /v "~~~"
# 32
```

Update: 
if you want to use it as R function, try this:

```
CountLines <- function(file) {
   stopifnot(file.exists(file))
   unlikely.pattern <- paste(sample(LETTERS), collapse = "")
   cmd <- sprintf('type %s | find /c /v "%s"', file, unlikely.pattern)
   res <- shell(cmd, intern = TRUE)
   return(as.integer(res))
}

CountLines("c:\\windows\\win.ini")
[1] 32
```

.
.
.

---

I found another way to do this more efficient, but I leave this to you for perfection:

```
> system("POWERSHELL Get-Content c:\\windows\\win.ini | Measure-Object -word -line -character", intern=TRUE)
[1] ""                                                                               
[2] "              Lines               Words          Characters Property           "
[3] "              -----               -----          ---------- --------           "
[4] "                 32                  38                 414                    "
[5] ""                                                                               
[6] ""
```